# remove mp4 metadata with script

Tags: python, metadata, vbscript, mp4

I want to remove meta data from a bunch of MP4 video files. I would like to do this without remux as that would take a long time. I am opened to a batch/powershell/python/vbscript solution.

I have tried ffmpeg and it works but only with muxer.

This can be done manually in windows explorer even with multiple files selected and no muxing necessary, just near instant results.

OS: Windows 10 1903

Answer (score 1):

ExifTool has the ability to write to MP4 files and can remove the most common types of metadata and has powerful batch processing ability without having to create a script

Try this command on a test file to see if it works well enough for you:
`exiftool -All= <FILE.MP4>`

If that works, change FILE.MP4 to the directories you want to process.  You can list multiple directories and you can add `-r` to recurse into subdirectories.  Add `-ext MP4` to process only MP4 files if you recurse, as it will otherwise process all file types.

This command creates backup files.  Add `-overwrite_original` to suppress the creation of backup files.

Comment: getting `Error: 'read' atom is too large for rewriting`

Comment: Very large files?  You can try adding `-api largefilesupport` to the command and see if that works.  Otherwise the Windows executable version of Exiftool may not be the solution as there are some limitations on it with regards to very big files.  An alternative would be to install a 64 bit version of Perl and use the pure Perl version of ExifTool.

Comment: it's a little weird because the files are only ~20MB

Comment: If they're that small, then you might come over to the [ExifTool forums](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/) and provide a sample via dropbox or similar service. The author will probable want to see it and figure out why it isn't supported.